# Highcharts - how to dynamically disable plotBorder without recreating a chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm using highcharts and want to achieve:

1. at beginning chart `plotBorder` is enabled
2. click a button and dynamically disable its `plotBorder`

I don't want to create a new `chartOption` with most of things remain the same and only change `plotBorderWidth` so I tried to update only this setting in 2 ways:

1. `chart.plotBorderWidth = 0`
2. `chart.options.chart.plotBorderWidth = 0`

but no matter I used chart.render() or chart.redraw() after above, `plotBorder` didn't disappear.

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V7weT/2/

Comment: I have tried `chart.isDirty = true;` and `chart.plotBorderColor = '#FFFFFF';` But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify SVG graphic element:

http://jsfiddle.net/V7weT/3/

```
 chart.plotBorder.attr({
        'stroke-width':0,
        'strokeWidth':0
    });
```

Comment: Nice. I've tried `attr` before with no success. Just curious how did you know it is `plotBorder` with `chart.plotBorder.attr`? By inspecting element, I could not found it.

Comment: I use a console.log() on chart object, which return objects / function in Firebug / Chrome console.